# Choosing crystal, strangely narrow requirements in MCU datasheet?

Tags: microcontroller, clock, capacitance, crystal

I am making a prototype using the Atmel ATSAM4S2B microcontroller, but I am having trouble choosing a crystal. I need a 12MHz crystal to use the integrated USB module.

The problem is, in the datasheet of the MCU, it says "allowed crystal capacitance load" must be between 12.5 pF and 17.5 pF.

https://i.gyazo.com/e617a28de6322e6060544194aefc8751.png

This is a problem, such a crystal seems to be quite rare. I tried looking up those specs in digikey, and when filtering out out-of-stock items, I am left with only three products, all of which are quite expensive (two of them VERY expensive I think) and all of them also having a no-lead DFN footprint which is unfortunate as small-run manufacturing will be expensive or hard.

http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/crystals-and-oscillators/crystals/852333?k=&FV=fff4000d%2Cfff8016d%2C8c0001%2C8c0004%2C8c0005%2C8c0009%2C8c000c%2C8c001f%2C8c0020%2C8c0032%2C8c0033%2C22c019d&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25

My question is, am I misunderstanding something here? It just seems so strange that a crystal that fits the required spec is so rare. What happens if I choose a crystal with a load capacitance of for example 12 or 18 pF, both of which are much more common?

Comment: Use a 12pF crystal and a board layout providing at least 0.5pf stray capacitance, Or see Andy's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misreading what it says in the data sheet I believe: -

[image]

The MCU spec is 17 pF maximum.

The XTAL they chose to demonstrate how to calculate \$C_{LEXT}\$ has a requirement for a load of between 12.5 pF and 17 pF. This isn't an MCU spec as such.

So, choose a 12pF crystal and calculate \$C_{LEXT}\$ based on the formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Having had the same problem, I settled on using an oscillator instead of a crystal. I saw no downside, as they start at 60 cents and need no external components, like the crystal does.

Digi-Key has over 250 different ones in stock:

http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/crystals-and-oscillators/oscillators/852334?FV=22c019d%2Cfff4000d%2Cfff8016e&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&pbfree=0&rohs=0&k=&quantity=&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25

Of course, not all will work for you - Some will be 5 volt only, some will be 3.3 volt only, and some will have sine-wave output.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question, more like a workaround. Sure, there are 250 oscillators in stock, but there are five times more crystals, which are five times cheaper.